# How can I make chart day to day objects count in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

My question is I need to make a dashboard page. In that, I need to make a chart on day to day created objects by the specific user in Django like the image below.
[image]

**Also, I need to know how to save data for this like charts.**

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options if you want to create charts. Most of them are JS and/or Ajax which you can include in the template page. Try this Google Charts which I believe is the simplest way to get things up and running,

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

You can use the parameters from the context dictionary to generate a dynamic graph.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Sangeeth. My doubt, how can I save the data to the database?. I need to save the count by day to day creating objects for each user or any other way?

Comment: Can you explain with a simple scenario ?

Comment: I had attached an image that shows one day how many problems the user solved same as that I need to display in my chart. How can I pass the data to this chart?

Comment: You have the number of problem solved by the user and you want that data sent to the template and rendered dynamically is that right ?? Let me answer that as a separate answer please check and verify if that is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

1 From views.py Send the Value of the data (ie the number of Problems solved) through the context Dictionary.

ex: **views.py**

```
def index(request):
        context = {"problems_solved" : calculated_value}
        return render(request, "results.html", context)
```

in the Template HTML do the following ,

**results.html:**

```
{% extends "base.htm" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    results
{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      
      var solved = {{problems_solved}};  
        
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['day', 'problems solved'],
          ['prob solved', solved ]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Profile progress Report: '
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
{% endblock %}



{% block body %}
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;">
{% endblock %}
```

If you are looking it to be generated everyday dynamically then you need to append values based with date to the context dictionary and execute the form generation everytime the page gets loaded